# Best way to connect to SQL Server 2012 remotely from a C# app

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I'm writing a simple C# program and want to use an SQL server to store entries from a few users.  It works fine locally but I haven't been able to connect using TCP.  I setup remote connections and enabled TCP in the config manager.  I keep getting this error.

> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

My connection string is

"Data Source=127.0.0.1\WEBSTORAGE;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=Characters;User Id=userid;Password=password;"

Comment: can you connect to the server using SSMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `Data Source` in connection string. `127.0.0.1` is an IP for `localhost`. Replace it with SQL Server machine's IP address or computer name.

Here's a good overview for connection string syntax: http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Edit:

It appears this was a problem with [SQL Server Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) service turned off. It's necessary when you are accessing named SQL Server instances over the network.

Comment: It's on the same machine for testing, I thought that would still work until I try connecting from a different machine.

Comment: @miroslav Popovic and what if I want to connect to a remote machine with a different ip will this method work?

Comment: It should work locally though, I know it wouldn't from a remote machine.  I would change the connection string to my external IP, I've already made a firewall entry but the point is shouldn't it work like this if everything is local?  So far the only way it works is with (local) as the server.

Comment: Even if the client is on the same machine though I should be able to use the external IP or the loopback and still get connected I would think.  I was wondering if I missed something in the configuration.  I even tried turning off the windows firewall.

Comment: @ankitsuhail I have included a link to various possible connection strings. This connection string should work if everything is set up correctly.

Comment: Is the SQL Server instance name WEBSTORAGE? Also, try using the IP address to connect using SSMS. That will make it easier to find an IP that works.

Comment: My connection string is exactly like the example, except I never found an example that used the instance name.  I was mostly wondering if there was a configuration option I missed.  I enabled TCP and allowed remote connections.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: @JeffSiver yeah the instance is WEBSTORAGE.  I've never used SSMS, I just wanted a few tables to connect to remotely to store data.

Comment: @Jason Also make sure your SQL Server Browser service is started, since you are using SQL Server instance name.

Comment: @JeffSiver lol sorry, I was thinking SSMS was the reporting part, I can't connect with SSMS either, I tried even specifying TCP in the options.  Something must be wrong in the configuration.

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic Hey that was it!  I had to enable the Browser Service.  It works fine now!